# How do i display the lifecycle events occuring in android on screen through textview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to display the lifecycle events that occur like `onCreate()`, `onPause()` etc. on screen of the emulator as and when it occurs. How can I do that. Thanks.

Comment: You won't see most of them since the UI isn't showing in most lifecycle callbacks. A better option would be to override the methods and write to logcat.

Comment: You're main goal is to better understand the lifecycle, I would recommend seeing here https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle

Comment: Each time one of the life cycle methods is called the name of the method should be added to the TextView. How do I do that

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial on this here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_acitivities.htm
As @George Mulligan commented better to use logcat.

```
@Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      Log.d(msg, "The onCreate() event");
   }
```

Comment: That shows in the LogCat. I want to display it on the screen of the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I tried showing a message in a textview and it works. I @overrided onPause() method in MainActiviy , and called the setContentView() method before setting Text to textview. I called setContentView both in @Override of onCreate() and in  @Override of onPause().  Try the following code :

```
    package com.example.secondtest;

    import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

         
         
         TextView textView;

         String Experiment = " Message in TextView after activity is stopped";

    @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      }   
    @Override
          protected void onPause() {
          super.onPause();
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
          textView.setText(Experiment);
}
}
```